# The display issue on StackOverflow

Tags: bug

I happended to see this on StackOverflow on page [Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context),the attribtue of the picture is displayed.
[image: Display issue]
System environment:

1. Operating System:Ubuntu 12.04
2. Browser:Version 31.0.1650.63 Ubuntu 12.04 (31.0.1650.63-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~20131204.1)

Comment: OK, shall I delete this issue or do someting?

Comment: It's not a problem to keep this closed question; it might very well be removed automatically at some point. Deleting is fine too, but will cost you the 5 reputation that you got from this, and like on any site on Stack Exchange: don't delete too much as that might trigger [the automatic question ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997). Instead, next time be sure to search before posting. Also, as an aside: watch your whitespace! Stack Overflow needs a space in its name, and punctuation such as commas, dots and colons need a trailing space.